# Retain cycle with strong reference to dispatch_queue

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

In a class, I've declared a thread like:

`@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t databaseQueue;`

and then I perform an operation this thread like

```
dispatch_async(self.databaseQueue, ^{
        [self.dao deleteRetries];
    });
```

Can this potentially create a retain cycle?

**AND**

the current class holds a strong reference to `viewControllerToDismiss` and there is a code which looks like:

```
[viewControllerToDismiss dismissViewControllerAnimated:shouldAnimateDismiss completion:^{

   [self performSomeAction];
}
```

is this a retain cycle?

Comment: NO It will not, iOS 6 and later—Dispatch objects (including queues) are Objective-C objects, and are retained and released automatically.

Comment: For Second scenario also will not create retain cycle until  Both ViewCOntroller contains strong ref of each other

Comment: GCD does **not** cause retain cycles although there are many people who assert that. It's a urban legend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is merely a strong reference to `self` that is eliminated automatically when the block finishes running and GCD releases the block. Note, this is a strong reference between the queue object itself, the block, and `self`, but not to `databaseQueue`. E.g. even if `databaseQueue` was some local reference that had fallen out of scope after you dispatched but before it ran, you'd still have a strong reference between the queue object, the block, and `self`.

If you don't want that strong reference at all, use `weakSelf` pattern:

```
typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
dispatch_async(self.databaseQueue, ^{
    [weakSelf.dao deleteRetries];
});
```

---

You asked:

> Please could you elaborate more on "Note, this is a strong reference between the queue object itself, the block, and self, but not to databaseQueue"?

Consider:

```
- (void)runManyTasks {
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.domain.app.foo", 0);

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            [self doSomething];
        });
    }
}

- (void)doSomething {
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
}
```

Even though I have no references in my code to that local variable, `queue`, after `runManyTasks` finishes, if I call `runManyTasks`, GCD will keep its own strong reference to the actual underlying queue object until all tasks finish, and the queue will keep copies of those blocks until they finish running, and those blocks will maintain a strong reference to `self` until GCD finishes with all of them (roughly 10 seconds, in this example).

---

You go on to edit your question and ask:

> the current class holds a strong reference to `viewControllerToDismiss` and there is a code which looks like:
>
> ```
> [viewControllerToDismiss dismissViewControllerAnimated:shouldAnimateDismiss completion:^{
>      [self performSomeAction];
>  }
> ```
>
> is this a retain cycle?

For all practical considerations, no. That block is released as soon as the dismissal animation is done, so you generally wouldn't complicate your code with `weakSelf` pattern here. In fact, that view controller isn't dismissed until the animation finishes, anyway, so there's absolutely nothing gained from `weakSelf` pattern (other than making code more convoluted).

Comment: Please could you elaborate more on `Note, this is a strong reference between the queue object itself, the block, and self, but not to databaseQueue`

Comment: @prabodhprakash See revised answer above with illustrative example.

Comment: One more question, so lets suppose, all these codes were written in `class A` and some other class (`class B`) is holding on to reference of `A` and while this function `runManyTasks` is running, I try to remove reference of `A` in `B`. How will the whole scenario behave? Will `A` be removed immediately from memory? or will `A` be removed after the loop has finished working?  or will `A` forever remain in memory as dangling pointer?

Comment: Just try it. Add `dealloc` method that logs something when it runs, and put something in the closures that log something when they run, and you'll see precisely what the timing is.

Comment: Got it, so if I've strong reference to self in the queue operation and `class A` is requested to be out of memory, it will continue to be in memory until the loop has finished. However, if we've passed a `weakSelf` - as soon as the `A` is asked to be `nil` - the loop continues, but `A` ceases to be in memory. Also, I now know that `retain cycle` does not necessarily mean `memory leak`

Comment: Yep. By the way, we don’t generally refer to “retain cycle” anymore. Since, with ARC, we focus on strong references, we use the term “strong reference cycle” now, though the terms are largely interchangeable.

Comment: Can you also help me with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46214876/having-retain-cycles-in-code-when-its-not-causing-memory-leak

Answer (score 4):

First, you have not declared a *thread*. It’s a queue, that’s something different. (Fortunately, as working directly with threads is a pain.)

You are dispatching a block into the queue. The block retains `self` and the queue retains the block, which means you *do* have a retain cycle, since the queue, being a `strong` property, is retained by `self`:

```
self -> queue -> block -> self -> queue -> …
```

BUT the block should be short-lived, judging by the API. When the block is finished, it will get released from the queue, breaking the retain cycle. So I would not worry about a case like this.

Comment: But, would you recommend passing weak self in it? as a good practice?

Comment: I've added one more scenario, if you could please amend your answer.

Comment: As for the weak `self`, it depends™. If you pass a weak `self` in, the owning object (`self`) may get deallocated before the block finishes, which means the call to DAO could not happen. Does it matter? If it does, keep the strong pointer and `self` will be released (and potentially deallocated) after the DAO finishes.

Answer (score 1):

Using self directly in blocks will create strong retain cycle.

To avoid retain cycle, please check below code

```
__weak YourViewController *weakSelf = self;
dispatch_async(self.databaseQueue, ^{
     if (weakSelf){
        YourViewController *strongSelf = weakSelf;
        [strongSelf.dao deleteRetries];
      }
    });
```

For more info visit this link [Working with blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html)